# P5.JS 3D Dot Diagram rendering extremely slow

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to convert a normal 2D image(a simple JPEG) into a 3D Dot Diagram that the user can move around with. But upon trying to render that dot diagram, the program becomes extremely slow. Can anyone point where I am going wrong?

```js
var x = [];
var y = [];
var z = [];
var colors = [];
var a = 0;
var counter = 0;

let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/clooney.jpeg');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 400, WEBGL);
  background(0);

  img.resize(width / 3, height / 2);

  for (let col = 0; col < img.width; col += 3) {
    for (let row = 0; row < img.height; row += 3) {
      let c = img.get(col, row);
      let rgb_val = c[0] + c[1] + c[2]
      colors[a] = c
      x[a] = map(col, 0, 255, -125, 125)
      y[a] = map(row, 0, 255, -125, 125)
      z[a] = map(rgb_val, 0, 765, -50, 0)
      stroke(c)
      push();
      a++
    }
  }

}

function draw() {
  translate(0, 0, -50);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.1);
  background(0);

  for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    stroke(colors[i])
    push();
    translate(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
    sphere(1);
    pop();
  }

  orbitControl();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Drawing 3d primitives in p5.js does not scale well when you get into the thousands of objects. I think you might be able to do something with custom geometry and UV coordinates, but it would be quite complicated. Unfortunately WebGL doesn't support geometry shaders which could also do something like this with much better performance. You could consider switching to Three.js which I think is better at optimizing persistent 3d geometry: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-optimize-lots-of-objects.html

Comment: Also, make sure you are using a web browser that supports hardware accelerated WebGL. I had to stop using FireFox because it is inexplicably incapable of using the GPU on my MacBook Pro with p5.js & WebGL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, drawing individual primitives in large quantities is relatively slow in p5.js. 3d graphics are best optimized when triangles are drawn from large vertex buffers (basically you precompute points in 3d space, their normal vectors for lighting, and a list of triangles that reference those points by index into the buffer). So the real winner here is the second sketch which generates some `p5.Geometry` for your grid of dots and uses texture coordinates to achieve the desired colors for each dot.

Experimenting with detail for the sphere, and switching between using stroke and fill for the spheres (minimal impact on my system):

```js
var x = [];
var y = [];
var z = [];
var colors = [];
var a = 0;

let img;

let fpsDisplay;
let strokeCheckbox;
let detailSlider;
let lastTime = 0;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/clooney.jpeg');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 400, WEBGL);
  background(0);

  img.resize(width / 3, height / 2);

  for (let col = 0; col < img.width; col += 3) {
    for (let row = 0; row < img.height; row += 3) {
      let c = img.get(col, row);
      let rgb_val = c[0] + c[1] + c[2];
      colors[a] = c;
      x[a] = map(col, 0, img.width, -125, 125);
      y[a] = map(row, 0, img.height, -125, 125);
      z[a] = map(rgb_val, 0, 765, -50, 0);
      a++;
    }
  }

  fpsDisplay = createInput('0');
  fpsDisplay.position(10, 10);
  strokeCheckbox = createCheckbox('Stroke', false);
  strokeCheckbox.position(10, 50);
  strokeCheckbox.style('color', 'red');
  detailSlider = createSlider(1, 24, 24);
  detailSlider.position(10, 90);
}

function draw() {
  // translate(0, 0, -50);
  // rotateY(frameCount * 0.1);
  background(0);
  orbitControl(2, 1, 0.1);

  noStroke();
  noFill();
  let useStroke = strokeCheckbox.checked();
  let detail = detailSlider.value();
  for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    if (useStroke) {
      stroke(colors[i]);
    } else {
      fill(colors[i]);
    }
    push();
    translate(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
    sphere(1, detail, detail);
    pop();
  }
  
  let t = millis();
  fpsDisplay.value(`${1000 / (t - lastTime)}`);
  lastTime = t;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Using p5.Geometry, UV coordinates, and texture (this hits 60 FPS on my system):

```js
const dotRadius = 1;
const detail = 4;

let img;

let fpsDisplay;
let lastTime = 0;

let geom;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/clooney.jpeg');
}

function setup() {
  console.log('Initializing');
  createCanvas(720, 400, WEBGL);
  // Because the spheres are so small, the default stroke makes them all black.
  // You could also use strokeWeight(0.1);
  noStroke();

  img.resize(width / 3, height / 2);

  const dotGrid = function() {
    const sliceCount = this.detailX + 1;
    let dotNumber = 0;
    for (let col = 0; col < img.width; col += 3) {
      for (let row = 0; row < img.height; row += 3) {
        let c = img.get(col, row);
        let rgb_val = c[0] + c[1] + c[2];
        let xOff = map(col, 0, img.width, -125, 125);
        let yOff = map(row, 0, img.height, -125, 125);
        let zOff = map(rgb_val, 0, 765, -50, 0);
        for (let i = 0; i <= this.detailY; i++) {
          const v = i / this.detailY;
          const phi = PI * v - PI / 2;
          const cosPhi = cos(phi);
          const sinPhi = sin(phi);

          for (let j = 0; j <= this.detailX; j++) {
            const u = j / this.detailX;
            const theta = 2 * PI * u;
            const cosTheta = cos(theta);
            const sinTheta = sin(theta);
            const p = createVector(
              xOff + dotRadius * cosPhi * sinTheta,
              yOff + dotRadius * sinPhi,
              zOff + dotRadius * cosPhi * cosTheta
            );
            this.vertices.push(p);
            this.vertexNormals.push(p);
            // All vertices in each dot get the same UV coordinates
            this.uvs.push(map(col, 0, img.width, 0, 1), map(row, 0, img.height, 0, 1));
          }
        }

        // Generate faces for the current dot

        // offset = number of vertices for previous dots.
        let offset = dotNumber * (this.detailX + 1) * (this.detailY + 1);
        let v1, v2, v3, v4;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.detailY; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < this.detailX; j++) {
            v1 = i * sliceCount + j + offset;
            v2 = i * sliceCount + j + 1 + offset;
            v3 = (i + 1) * sliceCount + j + 1 + offset;
            v4 = (i + 1) * sliceCount + j + offset;
            this.faces.push([v1, v2, v4]);
            this.faces.push([v4, v2, v3]);
          }
        }

        dotNumber++;
      }
    }
    console.log(`Dots: ${dotNumber}`);

    console.log(`Vertices: ${this.vertices.length}`);
    console.log(`Faces: ${this.faces.length}`);
  };

  geom = new p5.Geometry(detail, detail, dotGrid);
  geom.gid = 'dot-grid';

  fpsDisplay = createInput('0');
  fpsDisplay.position(10, 10);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  orbitControl(2, 1, 0.1);

  texture(img);
  model(geom);

  let t = millis();
  fpsDisplay.value(`${1000 / (t - lastTime)}`);
  lastTime = t;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing aswer (+1) ! I had a quick go using `beginShape()`/`endShape()` which seemed to work fast enough, however `stroke()` before `vertex()` didn't work as reliably in p5.js as it does in Processing.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Yeah, my understanding is that p5.js does not support per vertex stroke or fill settings when using beginShape/endShape (I tried that too). In any case p5.Geometry will always be the fastest option because the vertices and faces get pre-converted and cached as WebGL compatible buffers, although clearly it is not the easiest thing to code. I think there is an opportunity to create a Geometry type that lets you actually draw Geometry using the existing primitives & beginShape/endShape that you can then reuse (like you would creating re-usable 2d drawing with createGraphics).

Comment: Wow, thank you Paul for fixing this, I really gave up coz I thought it was impossible to build something like this. I'm sure even George Clooney would be impressed 

Comment: @PaulWheeler Could you explain the dotGrid function, I'm having trouble understanding it?

Comment: Here's an article I wrote about p5.Geometry that might help explain: https://www.paulwheeler.us/articles/custom-3d-geometry-in-p5js/